# Is it possible to quip "My package went to Nanjing, but I'm in Beijing; that's the complete opposite Jing"?

Tags: grammar, humor

I'm trying to quip

> My package went to Nanjing, but I'm in Beijing; that's the complete opposite Jing.

For it to be funny in English, the reader would have to know that 京 in Nanjing 南京 and Beijing 北京 is the same, and the joke is a play on how 南 and 北 are opposites.

Here's my attempt at writing it, which is a fairly literal translation:

> 我的快递发到了南京，但是我在北京。那儿是完全相反的“京”。

It's meant to be a joke.  However, I'm uncomfortable with the atypical grammar here.  I'm not sure it's even possible to express this in Chinese.

**Question**: Is it possible to quip "My package went to Nanjing, but I'm in Beijing; that's the complete opposite Jing"?

Comment: 这让我想起一名专门翻译国家文稿的翻译员讲过的一些翻译难点，其中就有一句毛主席说过的，"（大概讲的是革命的必然性）就算没有我毛泽东，也还坐有毛泽西。"这个就特别难翻译。当然，他也没讲具体是怎么翻译的。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

我的包裹发到了南京，但是我人在北京，一个完全相反的「京」！
我的包裹发到了南京，但是我人在北京，怎么没发到东京？
我人在北京，但是我的包裹却偏偏背道而驰，跑到南京去了！
我人在北京，但是我的包裹却和我渐行渐远，往南京去了！

Comment: I like the second one: 我的包裹发到了南京，但是我人在北京，怎么没发到东京？

Comment: @Sylvia While this is funny, you will be surprised on how many Staffs taking the joke seriously with your package actually ends up in Tokyo

Comment: @Alex right, it depends on the context whether to use it or not...

Comment: @sylvia Sorry, I missed a **的** in the first sentence.

Comment: @Alex Sorry, I missed a **的** in the first sentence.

Answer (score 2):

In speech, you can say: 我人在'北'京，快递却发到了'南'京.

It would add some joking effect when you put a bit emphasis on 北 and 南.

You don't have to say they are opposite literally. Your audience would seize that from your tone, which is the whole point of the joke.

Answer (score 1):

Your translation is accurate, but the point is that the original joke isn't funny, thus making the translation strange.

Advice 1:

Better not state both 北京 & 南京.

快递投给了南京，跟我在的京城反了个边。

Advice 2:

Better not play on 南 & 北.

我人在北京，快递给发了南京，真是中南海的文件发了总统府。

Answer (score 1):

My package went to Nanjing, but I'm in Beijing; that's the complete opposite Jing.
我的包裹去了南京，但我在北京，这是两个完全反方向的京！